# Doctrine 2 The table with nam does not exist

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am trying to run the schema create tool with Doctrine. My db is postgresql. I currently get the error:

```
  [Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\SchemaException]              
  The table with name 'tracon.users' already exists.
```

The error only occurs when I try to run with more than one Entity:

```
php vendor/bin/doctrine orm:schema-tool:update
```

or

```
php vendor/bin/doctrine orm:schema-tool:create
```

As an example. If I the Users entity the only entity in the folder, it works!

```
<?php
namespace entities;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Table;

// entities/Users.php

/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="users")
 * @Table(schema="development")
 **/
class Users {
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @Id
     * @Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @Column(type="string", length=64)
     */
    protected $username;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @Column(type="string", length=64)
     */
    protected $first_name;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @Column(type="string", length=64)
     */
    protected $last_name;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $email;

}
```

But as soon as I add another Entity class like the 'Media' one below, it complains the table already exist:

```
<?php
namespace entities;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping;

// entities/Media.php

/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="development.media")
 **/
class Media {
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @Id
     * @Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * 
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @Column(type="string", length=64)
     */
    protected $file_name;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @Column(type="string", length=64)
     */
    protected $file_url;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @Column(type="string", length=64)
     */
    protected $file_extension;


}
```

What could be causing this error? Also it appears the schema is not registering.

Comment: Since the error mentions it, are you sure the table does not already exist? `The table with name 'tracon.users' already exists.`

Comment: Positive, I even drop the db and still get that error.

Comment: Test change `@Table(name="users")` by ``@Table(name="`users`")``

Comment: @Yonel Just added an update. It works if the Users entity is the ONLY class. But as soon as I an another class it throws the already exist error.

Answer (score 1):

Cache! Clearing the cache with this command solved the problems:

```
php vendor/bin/doctrine orm:clear-cache:metadata
```

Comment: I still have the issue even after doing this, any ideas?